# CPU temp is hitting 83 C (181 F) in BIOS: Normal?

Tags: cpu, temperature

My BIOS is reporting that my Intel Core 2 Duo E6400 on a Asus P5B Deluxe is hitting 83 C (181 F). No overclocking.

I haven't done anything intensive at all. Just to check SpeedFan hits similar temperatures.

I thought it was a case fan that I might have put in backwards after cleaning it but that isnt it either.

What is the next thing I should do? Unmount the heatsink/fan on the CPU and remount it? The only thing Ive done is turn that case fan.

Ill have to do it tommorow as I have no thermal paste.

Comment: can u edit your post with CPU/MB specs?

Comment: Add more information as requested.

Answer (score 1):

No. That's very poor thermal behavior. I run an i7 quad that tops out at about 65 under load.

First, remove the left side panel of your PC while it's running. Is the CPU fan functioning? Next, inspect the ventilation ports in your case and clean if necessary.

Unplug the power and other cables from the PC. Inspect the CPU heatsink fins to see if they're gunked up. If so, use canned air to clear them. Don't tilt the can, and DO NOT allow the fan to spin while blowing it off. Hold it in place with a finger. Canned air can kill fans.

If these regular maintenance actions don't resolve the issue, you will want to get the supplies necessary to reseat your heatsink.

- Thermal paste (I use OC extreme)
- Rubbing alcohol
- Lint free cloth
- Paper Towel

If you're unfamiliar with thermal paste application, go watch some youtube videos now.

Research how to remove your particular heatsink, do so, then clean all the old thermal paste from it and the CPU's heatspreader using a paper towel. Once the majority of thermal paste is removed, clean the heatsink contact area and CPU heatspreader with the alcohol. Don't splosh it everywhere. Once the alcohol is dry, apply a pea sized drop of new thermal compound to the center of the CPU heat spreader and then reattach the heatsink. See if that helps.

DISCLAIMER: You can break things by doing the steps previously mentioned. Unplug the power and other cables. Beware ESD.

Comment: Some of the software I use that may help you: RealTemp, CPU-z, GPU-z, intelburntest, diskspeed, OCCT, y-cruncher.

Comment: The CPU fan is indeed working. Im almost sure that somehow the heatsink got loose....how and why is beyond me

Comment: If that's the case, it should get a new application of thermal paste. CPUs don't like being reseated with compromised paste still in place. Hope you get it sorted.

Comment: Applied new thermal paste and its sitting at the BIOS now. Hitting 40C (104 F). Lets give a minute or two as I do live in a attic so....shouldnt keep going higher....

Comment: Great. Load up REalTemp and run y-cruncher for a bit. See what happens.

Comment: Shouldnt I wait till it stablizes in BIOS first? Its at 44C (111.2 F) and rising

Comment: Just for reference: I used Artic Silver 5 thermal paste. Their method was to first tint (or lightly smear) the bottom of the heatsink (I have a Noctua but I dont know the model (and honestly it is killing me not knowing the model, 8 pipes coming out, 1 fan, pretty big)) and then a vertical line over the CPU. It seems a BIT of a overkill to me but thats what they recommend for Core 2 Duos.

Comment: It's a good data point for troubleshooting, but unless I see an issue in the OS typically ignore the BIOS. Running up the CPU will help the thermal paste spread, so I always do it right away.

Comment: Never used y-cruncher so Im going with Prime95. Realtemp is marking 60 C and not going above that...

Comment: GZ. Looks like you're in good shape now.

Comment: 62 C....I dont know. I think I was hitting way less temperatures when I got this heatsink. At least CPU-Z says it isnt throlling slowing down the CPU like when it was at 83 C.I have to upgrade the CPU to a Q6600 in the following weeks so it kinda even makes me angrier that I dont know how to remove fully the heatsink to swap the CPU....since I do not know the model and cannot look up instructions.

Comment: 63 C is the max it has hit......Of course, all of this is at night. Im thinking of leaving it all night-24 hours just to make sure...

Comment: Shame: Restarted. I do not know if it was because of overheating or Windows Update. Im gonna do the same test this weekend. All night and part of the day to make sure that temps are real and stable.

Answer (score -1):

Seems you have some problems with air flux and fan power as Tcase in CPU datasheet shows:

http://ark.intel.com/products/27249/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E6400-2M-Cache-2_13-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB?q=core%202%20duo%20e6400 (check if this proccesor match with your one, your CPU info is poor).

you are over the normal Tcase:
TCase Temperature is the maximum temperature allowed at the processor Integrated Heat Spreader (IHS).

You can learn more about Computer Cooling with this reference:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cooling

I suggest you to check if your Fan and Heat Sinks is enough to cover your CPU heat considering in some countries we have more temperature than others that affect the delta between air temperature and CPU heat.

Answer (score -1):

Shut it down and check the processor fan. If it's getting hot sitting idle, there's something wrong and you should shut it off before the thermal range causes the processor to short out and die. I'm guessing the processor fan is dead or running at very low RPM. The heatsink could also be loose. The heat coming off that Core2Duo will need direct transfer to a thermal plate to dissipate the heat or bios will report high temps. Also, I'm assuming the CPU fan is actually plugged in and getting power.